# String containing '%d' being converted to 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, zingchart

I am rendering ZingChart inside react-native webview. I need to access zingchart's token using `%data-day` but whenever i try to use `%d` it prints `NaN`

Below is the sample code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  renderWeb = () => {
    return `
      <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>
          ${console.log('%d', ':data')}
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>
      `;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView source={{ html: this.renderWeb() }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `console.log` is treated as a format string wherein percent characters introduce substitution sequences.  They are loosely based on format strings used by the `printf` function in C. See under "Using string substitutions" in MDN's [console article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).

`%d` consumes the next unconsumed argument of the call to `console.log` and formats it as a number. Since `':data'` is not a number, Chrome converts it to the string 'NAN' in the log when testing in a browser. It is browser dependent however - Firefox converts it to a zero.

To log the string "%d", double up on the percent sign and code it as "%%d" in the format string. Just like in C :-)